# Heroku serving up old javascript files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app that I'm currently hosting on Heroku. I had been struggling to get the javascript working (the javascript was causing the assets to fail to compile). I finally got that fixed and now my app us pushing to Heroku, however, it seems to be serving up old assets. It's a rails app.

What is super strange is I used VIM in the Heroku bash and was able to see that the javascript files that were stored with Heroku were updated, but no matter which browser I use, I'm still getting the old file. I know because the old file had an alert that ran on the page load, and I cannot get it to go away, even though I've removed that alert.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm at a loss on this one.

Comment: Check with cleaning browser cache or open page in incognito mode

Comment: Did you restart the server? Are you using digest on the compiled assets? it should handle all cache problems since the hash changes when you change something inside the files.